# Python strange results

Tags: python, while-loop

I have the following piece of code with a pretty strange result.. at least not the one that I expect. I would like to show me the counting of even numbers in range (1,10) only in one row for that range. Any ideeas? Thanks!

**The code** :

```
count=0 
for number in range (1,10):
    if number % 2==0:
        count +=1
        print(number)
    print(f"I have {count} even number")
```

**Results** :

```
I have 0 even number
2
I have 1 even number
I have 1 even number
4
I have 2 even number
I have 2 even number
6
I have 3 even number
I have 3 even number
8
I have 4 even number
I have 4 even number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the sentence to only be printed after the loop finishes, simply move the print statement out of the loop:

```
count=0 
for number in range (1,10):
    if number % 2==0:
        count +=1
        print(number)
print(f"I have {count} even numbers")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
count=0 
str = ''
for number in range (1,10):
    if number % 2==0:
        count +=1
        str += f" {number}"
print(f"I have {count} even numbers: {str}")
```

Comment: very nice alternative.. even this result is awesome.                                                            2 4 6 8
I have 4 even number

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that your last print statement is not within your for loop.

```
count=0
for number in range (1,10):
    if number % 2==0:
        count +=1
        print(number)
print(f"I have {count} even number")
```